# Rails query foreign function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a list called modellist. I want to find all instances of Model where modellist[model.id]>0
How could i accomplish this using a query. 
right now i have this function

```
finalmodels = []
@models.each do |model|
  if modellist[model.id] >0
     finalmodels.push(model)
  end
end
@models = finalmodels
```

I want the same completed with this query, but i cant figure it out. so something like

```
Model.where( ... modellist[model.id]>0)
```

Comment: @tadman it is list of integers where modellist[model.id] = digit

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your queries operate entirely in the SQL domain, not the Ruby domain, so you must specify the query in terms of things that can be supplied as part of the query, such as numerical or string values, or conditions that can be applied to values stored in the database. The SQL server has zero knowledge of your application's internal state other than what you provide to it in the query, or have previously saved into the databases state.

Your challenge, as a developer, is to figure out how to transform the state you have in your application into something that the database can execute on. Maybe this means saving the `modellist` into the database so it can be involved in the query, or it could mean re-thinking the problem to come up with a different solution instead of fighting a war you can't win.

Comment: If it is a list of numbers, you should be able to extract the keys and do a simple query: `Model.where(:id => modellist.select { |k, v| v > 0 }.collect { |k, v| k })` This transforms the `modellist` Hash into an array of keys to fetch and then gets them.

Comment: i tried what u said, it didn't work exactly, so i looked into the collect method. i made this query, @models = Model.find(:all).collect{|m| modellist[m.id] > 0} , it doesn't throw an error there, but in a later line i need to call, @models = @models.sort {|mod1, mod2| modellist[mod2.id] <=> modellist[mod1.id]} to sort the list by modellist amount, this line worked before, but now i get the error undefined method `id' for false:FalseClass here

Comment: The `collect` method transforms one list into another, so you're converting your list to a series of `true` or `false` values, not what you intended. The example I gave first reduces the list with `select`, then transforms it. Also if you're sorting, read up on `sort_by` which makes that sort of thing much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, heres how it goes (this isn't exactly right but it's the closest real solution i can think of)

```
models = Model.find(:all).collect{|m| m }.reject{ |i| modellist[i.id] < 1 }
```

The collect part goes through all models (with parameter m) and assigns value after |m| (in this case m). After that, reject goes through with parameter i and rejects when condition (modellist[i.id] < 1) is a true statement. You could also do something like

```
models = Model.find(:all).collect{|m| (modellist[i.id] < 0)? m:otherval }
```

for when you want one of two vals

Comment: this isn't a query, but it's less code. I'd still love an answer to my problem (a query that completes this same task)